# javascript window.history.go(-1) in Chrome and Fire Fox refreshes the previous page but in Safari it works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually i am trying go back from my previous HTML page, the issue is the page get's refreshed instead of just retaining the values. This is in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari its working great.

I am using Html cache as below. From console i can see the files getting loaded int the cache and i have also checked the network the files are getting loaded from the cache. I have the meta tag also.

```
<html  lang="ko" manifest="cache.manifest">
<head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 10 Jan 2013  00:00:00 GMT" />
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public" >

    </head>
</html>
```

I tried this link also https://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/ but not useful.

How to load the pages from cache instead of the page reload on click of back

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Document.location.reload(false)
```

This should reload the page from your cache

Comment: $("#goBack").click( function(){
 window.history.go(-1);
 return false;
}              //this  my code where should i place reload(false)

Comment: Instead of window.history.go(-1); try Document.location.reload(false)
location= Your pervious page name

Comment: thanks, in first screen itself it has to be cached but the cache is not happening i am checking using following code but the evt.persitent is always 'false'   window.addEventListener("pageshow",pageShown, true);
window.addEventListener("pagehide", pageHidden, true); function pageShown(evt)
{
 console.log('Status ::>'+navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline');
 evt.persisted = true;
    if (evt.persisted)
        
}

function pageHidden(evt)
{
}